# Display Flex causing responsive issues

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container with 2 divs in it, image left 50% and text right 50%. The text section has a read more link that will expand it's containing div giving both the image and text more height, like so -

**Closed**

[image: Read More Closed]

**Open**

[image: Read More Open]

```css
div.feature {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

div.feature>div.feature-image {
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.feature>div.feature-image,
div.feature>div.feature-description {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature">
  <div class="feature-image" style="background-image: url('http://cablelabs.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Smart-Drugs-banner.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="feature-description">
    <div class="featured-description-container">
      <h3>Smart Drugs/Meds</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <br>
      <div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more-button-container">
        <a href="#" class="show_hide tech-read-more-button" style="display: inline-block;">Read Less</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using flex to achieve this functionality. This works on a full screen but when it goes down to smaller screen sizes the height of the image is `0`. Can anyone help explain why the image isn't showing on smaller screens?

Comment: Why do you have float for image and feature? They are flex items, take float off. You don't have any content in the image section because it's a background image. When your divs wrap, the image section will have no height because you got nothing in there, it only has a height when screen is larger due to your text container having a height and the image container is stretched to match that height which default for flex items

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've removed the float now. So is there a solution you can think of?

Comment: Use an image on smaller screens instead of a background image, or give the background image section a height

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in chrome

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept it.

Comment: When users spend their own free time helping you, the least you can do is to respond, and since you chose not to, I deleted my answer.  I also noticed you don't accept any of your question's answers. You are suppose to, to mark quality content. Not doing that will attract less users pay attention to your future questions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, can you explain how I mark a reply as the correct answer as I'm clearly missing something?